# AJAX Parameter to MVC Controller isn't NULL?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I've an dropdown list where I can choose location to filter my data.

I have an array which I post to my controller with AJAX. On my local computer I get the parameter to be null when I have not selected anything from my dropdown list, as expected. However, on my live website it seems like the variable is not null, since it queries the data, so the result is empty.

How can this be? I want the value to be null, so I can filter the data correctly.

Thanks,
Stefan

> JQuery

```
$("#main").on("click", "#submit-search-catalog", function () {
    var url = "/Home/Catalog";

    var locations = $("#County").val();

    if (url != "") {
        $.post(url, { locations: locations },
        function (data) {
            if (data) {
                $(".catalog-container").html(data);
            }
        }).fail(function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert("Error");
        });
    }

    return false;
});
```

> MVC Controller

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Catalog(int[] locations = null)
    {

        var companies = await db.Users.Where(u => u.IsVisibleInCatalog.Equals(true)).OrderBy(u => u.CompanyRegistrationDate).ToListAsync();

        //Sort locations
        if (!(locations == null || locations.Length == 0))
        {
            companies = companies.Where(c => locations.Contains(c.CompanyLocation) || c.CompanyLocation.Equals(1)).ToList();
        }

        var model = new CatalogViewModel
        {
            Companies = companies
        };

        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            return PartialView("~/Views/Home/_CatalogListPartial.cshtml", companyList);
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

> -- EDIT

I tried this for bug testing, and locally it alerts "empty" and serverside it alerts "null":

```
    if (locations == null)
        alert("null");

    if (locations.length == 0)
        alert("empty");
```

Comment: Did you check jquery version on your server ?

Comment: What does the html element look like? Can you post that?

Comment: Here is the [Website](https://www.foretagsuppdrag.se/home/catalog), I'm using razorview. I guess it would be easier to inspect that way?

Comment: No, your website can change. It's better to include the relevant html here so that the question can help others in the future.

Comment: I edited the @post. I'm using razorview though, under the html.

Comment: I understand you want to keep some of your data off of here, but that is definitely not the `<select>` tag that is rendered....you have "multiple" in your razor and it's not in your html, but this is a start.

Comment: The code is waaay to long for posting it, I can post it - No worries about the data. Is it possible to limit the "code-field" in here?

Comment: There, I updated the @post.

Comment: I think @orhun.begendi took care of your problem...you've got a version mismatch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On jquery select like 
$("#County").val(); 
could be version-based problem. On val() function; at jQuery 3.0, if no options are selected, it returns an empty array; prior to jQuery 3.0, it returns null. 
But its can be changed to object type like radiobutton or combo.

Comment: It's the same jQuery serverside and locally though, so that couldn't be an issue, or could it?

Comment: what is the version of your jquery that using ?

Comment: I'm using jQuery 3.1.1

Comment: what is the #County really what is that type ?

Comment: It's a bootstrap-select - It's the ID of the dropdown. Or did I misunderstood you?

Comment: no you didn't. I tried at my own system, before jquery 3.0 it return null, after 3.0 version it returns empy. you can check with console.logging with $.fn.jquery for version check. Could be cache or something. be sure versioning same on both sides. Sometimes when deploying wrong jquery package can be upload by visual studio.

Comment: Okay, so on my localhost it says 3.1.1 but on the live one it says 1.10.2.. Why is it like that, and how could I fix it?

Comment: I tried with a possible solution now and updated with the same jQuery version. However, I needed to use: BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false; to get it to work. Is that the correct way of doing it?

Comment: yes you can disable optimizations like that, be sure debug mode false in your web.config file. its to best way to do check it. For best practice prepare 2 type web.config debug and release mode. you can set it debug mode on your debug typed file and turn off on your release typed file.

Answer (score -1):

Do type checking in your script.
Instead of this:

```
if (url != "")
```

Try this:

```
 if (url !== "")
```

Comment: You're right, but it does work both ways though. Doesn't affect the problem I got.

Comment: If so, you have to log the value of url since you have no access to debugging on the server. Log and see what value is set to url when nothing is selected from drop down. Im really curious about this!

Comment: Alternatively, try to set an always-be option to the dropdown list(like 'none') and set is as default option. You can filter your data based on 'none' value,not the empty string. This way, your dropdown selected option will not be a dangling thing(as it seems to be here)

Comment: @ethorn10 sorry for hurry. My comments where about county.